# URL works Fine in browser but gives 404 error with ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello i am working on a PHP script and i am facing an issue that when i open the URL from browser it opens successfully but when try to make ajax request it gives me 404 Error. My Code is Following

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url : "http://example.com/ajaxRequest/index.php",
            method : "POST",
            cache: false,
            data : {
                name : "Mohsin",
            },
            success : function(data){
                alert(data);         
            },
        });
```

Same URL opens in browser but gives 404 Error with ajax Request. i have also included

> header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

in above script

Comment: is it a cross origin request??

Comment: yes it is cross origin.

Comment: check in your console if it shows any errors

Comment: @syedmohamed yeah it gives 404 not find error.

Comment: Can you confirm you are receiving the cors header

Comment: @JaromandaX no there are no CORS issues.

Comment: What about adding header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

Answer (score 1):

Mention as cross domain request in your ajax. And also use `jsonp` for cross domain requests.

```
url : "http://example.com/ajaxRequest/index.php",
        method : "POST",
        cache: false,
        data : {
            name : "Mohsin",
        },
        crossDomain:true,    <---- add this line
         dataType : 'jsonp',   // also this line
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);         
        },
```

See about `jsonp` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about) and [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/tutorials/learn-how-to-use-the-jsonp-data-format-with-jquery.html#fbid=Ve0fjNmkFyt)

Comment: you are welcome. try that and let me know about the result.

Comment: Yes Sure :) .. i will let you know

Comment: Jsonp is a hack that shouldn't be required in this case with access to the server side code. It also requires not insignificant recoding on the server