# Codeigniter AJAX pagination on click error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a problem with jQuery. My codeigniter pagination is working, but when I add

```
        $(".search-pagination > ul > li > a").on("click",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:$(this).attr('href')
            }).done(function(data) {
                $(".grid-container-body").html(data.body);
                $(".search-pagination").html(data.pagination_link);                 
            });             
        });
```

I have a error on `jquery.min.js` on this part

```
 i.send(c.hasContent && c.data || null), d = function(a, e) {
                        var h, j, k, l, m;
                        try {
                            if (d && (e || i.readyState === 4)) {
                                d = b, g && (i.onreadystatechange = p.noop, cJ && delete cI[g]);
                                if (e) i.readyState !== 4 && i.abort();
                                else {
                                    h = i.status, k = i.getAllResponseHeaders(), l = {}, m = i.responseXML, m && m.documentElement && (l.xml = m);
                                    try {
                                        l.text = i.responseText
                                    } catch (a) {}
                                    try {
                                        j = i.statusText
                                    } catch (n) {
                                        j = ""
                                    }!h && c.isLocal && !c.crossDomain ? h = l.text ? 200 : 404 : h === 1223 && (h = 204)
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (o) {
                            e || f(-1, o)
                        }
                        l && f(h, j, l, k)
                    },
```

this is a my function in controller

```
public function ordersItems()
{
    $data = '';
    $orderby = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 'ponuda_id';
    $order = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 'asc';
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = URL_PATH.'admin/orders/'.$orderby;
    $config['total_rows'] = (int)$this->m_administrator->itemsCount()['COUNT(orders_id)'];
    $config['per_page'] = 4;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $page = ($this->uri->segment(5)) ? $this->uri->segment(5) : 0;
    $data["result"] = $this->m_administrator->get($config['per_page'], $page, $orderby, $order);
    $data["pagination_link"]= $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data["order"] = $order;
    $data["orderby"] = $orderby;
    $is_ajax = $this->input->is_ajax_request();
    if(!$is_ajax){
        $data['user'] = $_SESSION['info'];
        $data['note'] = $this->m_administrator->getNotes($user = $_SESSION['info']['user_id']);
        $data['content'] = $this->load->view('admin/contents/orders', $data, true);
        $this->load->view('admin/admin',$data);
    }else{
        $output['body'] = $this->load->view('admin/contents/items/items-list', $data, true);
        $output['pagination_link'] =$data["pagination_link"].'
            <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $(".search-pagination > ul > li > a").on("click",function(e){
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "GET",
                                url:$(this).attr("href")
                            }).done(function(data) {
                                $(".tab-pane").html(data.body);
                                $(".search-pagination").html(data.pagination_link);
                            });
                        });
                    });
            </script>
                        ';
        $this->output
        ->set_content_type('application/json')
        ->set_output(json_encode($output));
    }
}
```

on console I have a error

> jquery.min.js:3246 GET http://localhost/site/admin/orders/orders_id/12  404 (Not Found)

But if I copy this link and paste on browser is OK

Comment: Is it a cross origin request? Check [URL works Fine in browser but gives 404 error with ajax request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729439/url-works-fine-in-browser-but-gives-404-error-with-ajax-request)